# SQL Server - Insert into a combination of two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, insert

I need to combinate two tables in SQL Server. But I need to have a row with each item of table A with each item of table B, resulting in a table C. I would be like this:

```
Table A
A
B
C
D

Table B
1
2
3

Table C
column x | cloumn Y
   A           1
   A           2
   A           3
   B           1
   B           2 
   B           3
   C           1
   C           2
   C           3
   D           1
   D           2
   D           3
```

Thanks all!

Comment: What are the names of the columns in `A` and `B`? Is the desired result in `C` a single concatenated column or two columns? Does table `C` already exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
SELECT 
 a.a + CAST(b AS VARCHAR(2)) AS a
FROM tablea a
CROSS JOIN tableb AS b;
```

See it in action:

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/79dc8/5)

Then you can use the [`INTO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx) clause to insert them into a table already exists:

```
INSERT INTO tablec(c)
SELECT 
 a.a + CAST( b AS VARCHAR(2)) AS a
FROM tablea a
CROSS JOIN tableb AS b;
```

or create a new table from these values:

```
SELECT 
 a.a + CAST( b AS VARCHAR(2)) AS c
INTO Tablec
FROM tablea a
CROSS JOIN tableb AS b;
```

[**Updated SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a84e5/4)

**Note that:** I assumed the columns' names, since you didn't specify them in your question.

Comment: Hi Mahmoud Gamal! I really appreciate your help!
But I was wrong.
I have edited the question, check that, please!

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud!
I used SQL Fiddle and everything is ok!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to get the following:

```
select a.col1, b.col1
into tableC
from tableA a
cross join tableB b
```